# Get property value by passing property name from XML

Tags: xml, powershell

How to get property value by passing property name from XML file using PowerShell. For example, The following is the XML file content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyProject>
  <!-- My Comment Here -->
  <MyPropertyGroup>
    <PropertyID>2</PropertyID>
    <PropertyName>ItsMyName</PropertyName>
  </MyPropertyGroup>
  <MyPropertyGroup>
    <MobileNo>3</MobileNo>
    <NickName>ItsMyNickName</NickName>
  </MyPropertyGroup>
</MyProject>
```

I tried like below:

```bsh
[xml]$file = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\MyTest.xml'
$file.ChildNodes[1].GetElementsByTagName("PropertyName")
```

But it return result as like:

```
#text
-----
ItsMyName
```

I want to get `ItsMyName` as result to store into variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand the property like this

```
$file.ChildNodes[1].GetElementsByTagName("PropertyName")."#text"
```

Or to be able to accept multiples results you could pipe it to `Select-Object` like this

```
$file.ChildNodes[1].GetElementsByTagName("PropertyName") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the nodes like properties:

```
$file.MyProject.MyPropertyGroup[0].PropertyName
```

**Output:**

```
ItsMyName
```

Comment: I want to pass the property name as parameter to get its value

Comment: `$file.MyProject.MyPropertyGroup[0].$param`

Comment: I want to pipeline the result to some other variable like below

$file.ChildNodes[1].GetElementsByTagName("Mail-Merge-Service-Name") | Out-String